# Estado "Ready for Review" en Appstoreconnect

Tags: ios

Estoy tratando de publicar una actualización de mi aplicación en App Store, Después de enviar varias veces a revisión mi app quedó en estado "Ready for review" y no he podido cambiarlo. He modificado el formulario de la app pero solo puedo guardar los cambios, el botón "submit to review" no aparece. Leí que en el apartado "App Review" debería tener la opción de enviar la app a revisión pero tampoco veo el botón.
Alguien sabe como puedo enviar esta versión a revisión o eliminarla para crearla de nuevo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]